# How can I arrive at a series expansion of $ (1+x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How can I arrive at a series expansion of $
(1+x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Is this a power series? I've tried using Maclaurin series, but I don't 
seem to be getting anywhere.

Please briefly explain to me how I can obtain a sensible solution.

Comment: Use binomial expansion

Comment: You cannot expect a Maclaurin expansion because it's derivative at $0$ is infinite. But you can get something very similar to a Maclaurin series using binomial formula.

Comment: Or you can use the MacLaurin expansion for $(1+u)^{1/2}$, then replace $u$ in the result by $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Eclipse, Isn't a binomial theorem/series derived from Maclaurin series? Thanks, I will also research more on this.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick, thanks.

Comment: @Clement, I will attempt that approach as well. If you can offer more guidance on it, then it would be better :).

Comment: @LucyM It's pretty much the same as the Binomial expansion, since the series coincide. But basically all I'm saying is that, if $f(u) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n u^n$ for $|u| < R$, then  $f(\sqrt{u}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n u^{n/2}$ for $0\leq u < R^2$.

Comment: (The result is not a MacLaurin expansion, since in general you end up with non-integer powers.)

Comment: @LucyM You're right. I mean that if you use binomial formula here you will get a series like $1+\frac12 x^{1/2}+\cdots$. But a power series must be $a_0+a_1x+\cdots$.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am now confident to attempt this question by myself.

Comment: @LucyM Just in case, I upgraded my comment to an answer to give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not going to be a Taylor (MacLaurin) series, since such a series is of the form $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ for $|x|< R$ (where $R$ is the convergence radius), i.e., it only has *integer* powers.

However, we can derive a similar series, with *fractional* powers. The reasion is that your function $f$ satisfies, for every $x>0$,
$$
f(x) = g(\sqrt{x})\tag{1}
$$
where $g(u) = (1+u)^{1/2}$ *does* have a MacLaurin expansion:
$$
g(u) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{n} u^n= 1+\frac{u}{2}-\frac{u^2}{8} + \dots\,,\qquad |u|<1. \tag{2}
$$
Consequently, we have that for every $0\leq x< 1$, since $\sqrt{x}< 1$,
$$
f(x) = g(\sqrt{x}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{n} x^{n/2} = 1+\frac{x^{1/2}}{2}-\frac{x}{8} + \dots\,. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: Thanks @Clement C

Comment: @LucyM You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The Generalized Binomial Theorem will be useful$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$Now set $n=\tfrac 12$ and replace $x$ with $\sqrt x$.

Comment: Thanks @Frank W